# ChangingResponse type at server side on click of button which is in updatepanel in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

Consider the following  ASP.NET Code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="operationPanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always" RenderMode="Block">
  <ContentTemplate >
    <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnSave" OnClientClick="return Client_Click()" ImageUrl="~/Images/Save_icon.png" OnClick="Server_Click" />
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSave" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And corresponding server code for button click is:

```
protected void btnPbsh_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
  Response.Clear();
  Response.BufferOutput = false;
  string fileName = "sample.zip";
  Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
  Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"sample.zip");
  Response.WriteFile(lclZipFileName);
  Response.Flush();
  Response.End();
}
```

Please ignore sytax and logical error.

```
On click of button it displays error like in IE
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'PK'.
```

and nothing happens in Firefox.

I am not able to figure out the error and the cause.

Thanks,

Amit Shah

Comment: Any join with my solution below? Can we offer any more assistance?

Answer (score 1):

Like the error says:

> Common causes for this error are when
>   the **response is modified** by calls
>   to Response.Write(), response filters,
>   HttpModules, or server trace is
>   enabled.

I had a similar issue while doing what you're trying to achieve. My solution was to use a Global Handler with the following code:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Download : IHttpHandler
{

    public override void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {

        string filePath = context.Server.MapPath(context.Request.QueryString["FilePath"]);
        string contentType = context.Request.QueryString["ContentType"];

        context.Response.Clear();
        context.Response.ContentType = contentType;
        context.Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(filePath));

        if (filePath != null)
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = this.GetFileBytes(filePath);
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(fileBytes);
            context.Response.Flush();
        }

    }

    protected byte[] GetFileBytes(string url)
    {

        WebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(url);
        byte[] fileBytes = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.GetResponse();


        Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        int chunkSize = 0;
        do
        {
            chunkSize = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, chunkSize);
        } while (chunkSize != 0);

        fileBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();

        return fileBytes;

    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Then to use the file, you call the above in JavaScript:

```
function Download(file, contentType) {
    try {
        location.href = "WebServices/Download.ashx?FilePath=" + file + 
                        "&ContentType=" + contentType;
    }
    catch (err) {
    }
    return false; // Return false to stop the page posting back
}
```

You can then call this on your button's `OnClientClick`:

```
return Download("sample.zip", "application/octet-stream");
```